# How to show that if $N \trianglelefteq S_n$ for $n \geq 5$ and $S_n/N$ abelian, then $N = A_n$ or $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $N \trianglelefteq S_n$ for $n \geq 5$ with $S_n/N$ abelian.
I'd like to show that $N = A_n$ or $S_n$.

We sort of breezed over the proof in class because it was either obvious to my professor or because he was running out of time.

We had already proved the theorem that $N \trianglelefteq G  \implies (G/N \text{ abelian } \iff G'\ \subseteq N)$. And I know that for $n \geq 5$, $A_n = S_n'$.

So $N \trianglelefteq S_n$ and $S_n/N$ abelian $\implies$ $S_n' = A_n \subseteq N \trianglelefteq S_n$.

I saw online that $A_n$ is the only proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$, which would finish the proof. But we didn't show this in my course yet. (At least I don't remember doing it.) I was wondering if there's another, simpler way to show this.

Comment: Here, it is simply the fact that the index of $A_n$ in $S_n$ is $2$ and that, since $A_n<N<S_n$, the index of $N$ in $S_n$ must divide it.

Comment: As a complementary observation, $S_n'=A_n$ for $n=3$ and $n=4$ too. And for $n=2$ too (as silly as the notation is in that case).

Answer (score 1):

Beside the comments, here is a short proof using the commutator group:

Consider the canonical projection $\pi\colon S_n\to S_n/N$ with $S/N$ abelian. Now $A_n=[S_n,S_n]\le \ker(\pi)=N\le S_n$. Because of Lagrange $|A_n|\le|N|\mid |S_n|$ and $\frac{|S_n|}{|A_n|}=|\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}|=2$. Then $N=A_n$ or $N=S_n$. $\qquad\square$

The "$\subseteq$" comes from the general fact:

Given a group homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to H$ with $H$ abelian, then $[G,G]\subseteq \ker(\varphi)$.